# How can I get information about properties of a style?

Tags: stylesheet

I'd like to make some features of my notebooks responsive to some properties of styles in the active stylesheet. Is there a way to do this? I can't seem to get anything out of `StyleData`. What I'm looking for is something of the form

```
StyleData["SomeStyle", "FontName"]
StyleData["SomeStyle", "FontSize"]
```

etc.

Are there functions or settings I can use to programmatically get information about properties of a style?

Comment: Open the stylesheet (possibly `Default.nb`). If necessary, choose a style from the "Choose a style" drop-down menu. Select the now-displayed cell named after that style. Now use the Option Inspector, either browsing for what you want in the outline hierarchy or else by using the Search box in the Option Inspector.

Comment: @murray: How can I do that in code? (See edit.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need

```
 CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, stylename}]
```

Examples:

```
 CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Section"}]
```

[image]

```
 CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Section", "CellFrame"}]
 (* {{0, 0}, {0, 1}} *)
 CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Subsection", "FontFamily"}]
 (* "Helvetica" *)
 CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Graphics", "CapForm"}]
 (* "Square" *)
```

etc.

Comment: Hey, do you know how to get the info for a particular screen environment such as printout?

Comment: It seems a particular option you can get with `CurrentValue[notebook, {StyleDefinitions, "style/Printout", theOption}]`, but I still haven't found how to get the whole list

Comment: Hi @Rojo, i don't know how to get the definitions for combo styles. I would expect/wish that using the stylenames (like `"Section/SlideShow"` or `StyleData["Section", "SlideShow"]`) would work; but it doesn't (ver 9 on windows vista). And, the option values returned by `CurrentValue[notebook, {StyleDefinitions, "style/Printout", theOption}]` do not match the defined/inherited values of these options based on the definitions in `Default.nb`. For example, `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Section/xx", "FontSize"}]` gives `14` for `xx` in `{"PrintOut","Condensed","Working","SlideShow"}`.

Comment: That's sad. Thanks!

Comment: It is possible to use `CurrentValue` to get some property of a style of the same stylesheet I'm defining? I.e. if I want to use the same `FontColor` many times and I don't want to write it explicitely all times? I tried but I get a wrong color... Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is just an addendum concerning screen environments. To obtain all the styles associated with an environment use a list as in:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {StyleDefinitions, {"Text", "Printout"}}]
```

> {CellMargins -> {{49, Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}}, 
>    Hyphenation -> True, LineSpacing -> {1, 3}, TabSpacings -> {2.5}, 
>    CounterIncrements -> "Text", MenuSortingValue -> 1400, MenuCommandKey -> "7",
>     FontFamily -> "Source Sans Pro", FontSize -> 15}

or to obtain a specific setting:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {StyleDefinitions, {"Section", "SlideShow"}, FontSize}]
```

> 40

Answer (score 1):

(Very incomplete answer!)

Open the style sheet, e.g.:

```
nb = NotebookOpen[
    "/Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/\
     Creative/PastelColor.nb"]
```

Find what you want, e.g., style for Section:

```
NotebookFind[nb, "Styles for Title and Section Cells"]
NotebookFind[nb, "Section"]
SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell]
```

Read it:

```
properties = NotebookRead[nb]
```

Of course to use my method, you already need to know in detail the structure of the style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

[Carl Woll'](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll)s [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184258/76328) using `CurrentValue` is definitely the way to go once you know exactly what properties you want, and you want to do so programmatically.

To expand upon [murray](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/148/murray)'s [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14538/76328) using `NotebookRead`, and to perhaps provide an answer directed towards the *title* of your post, here is a method that uses `NotebookRead` to make a "handy dictionary" of all properties in a stylesheet, that you can then search-through using normal *Mathematica* search features:

```
FormatStyleSheet = With[
    {
     defaultNBData = 
      First@Through@{NotebookRead@*Cells, NotebookClose}@
         NotebookOpen[
          FileNameJoin[
           {
            $InstallationDirectory,
            "SystemFiles",
            "FrontEnd",
            "StyleSheets",
            #
            }
           ],
          Visible -> False],
     Col = Column[#,
        Background -> {{LightBlue, LightYellow}},
        BaseStyle -> "Input",
        Alignment -> {Left, Center},
        ItemSize -> Scaled@1] &,
     CellsToNB = CreateDocument@*Cell@*CellGroupData,
     CloseGroups = Function[nb,
       SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
       FrontEndExecute@FrontEndToken@"SelectionCloseAllGroups";
       SelectionMove[nb, Before, Cell]]
     },
    
    CloseGroups@CellsToNB@ReplaceAll[
        c : 
          Cell[StyleData[___, OptionsPattern@StyleData], 
           definitions___] :>
         Sequence[c, Cell@BoxData@ToBoxes@Col@{
               StyleData -> OptionValue[StyleData, StyleDefinitions],
               definitions}]
        ]@defaultNBData
    ] &;
```

Usage:

```
FormatStyleSheet@"Default.nb"
FormatStyleSheet@"Core.nb"
```

Example output:

[image: Example output]

You can use the methodology in the above code (namely, `NotebookRead`) to get the values you want programmatically, of course, too.  But I think Carl Woll's method is more direct for that.