# Retrieve style definitions

Tags: notebooks, stylesheet

How can I retrieve the style definitions of a certain style within a cell, notebook or stylesheet?

For example how can I retrieve the `FontColor` and `FontFamily` of the `"Input"` style either in the current notebook or in `Default.nb`?  (Preferably without reference to an existing cell of this style.)

Comment: Is [this Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14876/125) relevant/useful?  I.e. perhaps something like `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Input", FontSize}]`?

Comment: And `CurrentValue[{DefaultStyleDefinitions, "Input", FontSize}]`

Comment: @kguler Yes, it is a duplicate, you can vote to close.  Thanks for the link!